# VMWARE create a Vm

Tags: vmware, powershell

I want create one template template from one modele with power cli.
I have esxi 6.5 and vcsa 6.7

Plese can you help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about VMWare / VSphere operations.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your configured VM into a VM Template is very simple.

```
Set-VM -VM <VM Name> -ToTemplate -Confirm:$false
```

Then you'll be able to see your template with the Get-Template command.

```
PS> Get-Template

Name 
----
<VM Name>
```